# How to convert json arry to xml in node.js

Tags: json, xml

1. Input: 
   It have a json object, such as "root" object
2. Output: 
   and now, how to convert to a  xml format like this:
3. Program Language, you can use node, java,etc

Input json object:

```
"root" :{
   "Yylb": {
       "Yylb_id": [1,2]
     },
   "Fj": [
     {
      "Fjxx":1
     },
     {
     "Fjxx":2
     }
  ]
}
```

Outpu xml format:

```
<root>
   <Yylb>
      <Yylb_id>1</Yylb_id>
      <Yylb_id>1</Yylb_id>
   </Yylb>
   <Fj>
      <Fjxx>1</Fjxx>
   </Fj>
   <Fj>
      <Fjxx>2</Fjxx>
   </Fj>
</root>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using this Node module: https://www.npmjs.com/package/js2xmlparser.

Example:

```
var js2xmlparser = require("js2xmlparser");

var data = {
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Smith"
};

console.log(js2xmlparser("person", data));

> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <person>
>     <firstName>John</firstName>
>     <lastName>Smith</lastName>
> </person>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [xml-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml-js)

Steps to use:-

Install-Package:- `npm install --save xml-js`

then add code this snippet:-

```
var convert = require('xml-js');
var xml =
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' +
'<note importance="high" logged="true">' +
'    <title>Happy</title>' +
'    <todo>Work</todo>' +
'    <todo>Play</todo>' +
'</note>';
var result1 = convert.xml2json(xml, {compact: true, spaces: 4});
var result2 = convert.xml2json(xml, {compact: false, spaces: 4});
console.log(result1, '\n', result2);
```

For more details Please visit :- [xml-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml-js)